# AngularJS. Using values/scopes from different controllers throughout the application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller

I understand that using $rootScope to share values between controllers is a bad idea and everybody recommends using Services and as an answer links to the the angular docs. However I am at loss there, because the official documentation does not show any simple example, and when I tried to implement some examples from here, StackOverflow – they did not work for me (maybe because I am using ng-repeat?). I have been trying to solve it for several days, as to not to bother you here, but now I am at totally at loss.

Could you please show me how to solve the example below, and I will then use it in my application (where I have about 50 different scopes used in 5 different controllers). The example below is the simple outline of my problem. I have also created a plunker for it http://plnkr.co/edit/J4fZ51koueyUX9mXqzDk?p=preview

**I have three controllers in my JS:**

```
app.controller('TotalCalc', function($scope) {

  });

app.controller('color', function($scope) {
  $scope.colors = [
  {name1: "Red",price1: 300},
  {name1: "Green",price1: 660},
  {name1: "Black",price1: 920}
];});

app.controller('coating', function($scope) {
  $scope.coatings = [
  {name2: "Single coating",price2: 2},
  {name2: "Double coatings",price2: 4},
  {name2: "Triple coating",price2: 7}
];});
```

**And in my HTML I have:**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="TotalCalc">
Here I want to calculate a value: (color selected price) * (coating multiplier)<br>
Using the "selected.price1" * "selected.price2", from the "color" and "coating" controllers below.

<div class="col-xs-6" ng-controller="color">
<strong>Color selected price: {{selected.price1 ||0}}</strong>
 <div class="list-group small">
  <a ng-repeat="color in colors" ng-click="$parent.selected = color" class="list-group-item" ng-class="{active:selected==color}"><span class="badge pull-right">$ {{color.price1}}</span>{{color.name1}}</a>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6" ng-controller="coating">
 <strong>Coating multiplier: {{selected.price2 ||0}}</strong>
 <div class="list-group small">
  <a ng-repeat="coating in coatings" ng-click="$parent.selected = coating" class="list-group-item" ng-class="{active:selected==coating}"><span class="badge pull-right">{{coating.price2}}</span>{{coating.name2}}</a>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

See, that whole place (single-page-application) is under the "TotalCalc" controller and from there I cannot access the values from the other two controllers inside it.

I understand that I should use the Service(?) somehow, if I want to access any values/scopes from the different controllers throughout the whole application. But after several days reading up and trying, I cannnot find a way for it to work. :( Can you please use my simplified example above, and to show me how it is done? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why use different controllers?

Comment: @Neikos Because I could not use different ng-repeat in one controller, and when I was chosing from one list, and then wanted to choose from another list, the selection from the first list got cancelled. That is why I put them in different controllers. But you gave me an idea, I will try it again, since I have different names for the values... EDIT: I have tried with different names, but no, it is still using all the lists in one controller as one big list, I cannot separate them. That's why I had to put them in separate controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Nikos pointed out, you really don't need multiple nested controllers here. That being said, here is an example of using a service as well as some custom events for communicating. The events aren't needed as you can bind all the data together through the service , but I put them in for inspiration

```
app.factory('CoatingService', function() {
  var thisService = {
    colors: [
      {name1: "Red",price1: 300},
      {name1: "Green",price1: 660},
      {name1: "Black",price1: 920}
    ],
    coatings: [
      {name2: "Single coating",price2: 2},
      {name2: "Double coatings",price2: 4},
      {name2: "Triple coating",price2: 7}
    ],

    selected:{
      color:{},
      coating:{}
    }
  }

  return thisService

})

app.controller('TotalCalc', function($scope, CoatingService) {
  $scope.selected=CoatingService.selected;
 function updateTotal(){
      $scope.totalprice= ($scope.selected.color.price1 ||0) + ($scope.selected.coating.price2||0)
 }
 updateTotal();

 $scope.$on('doPriceUpdate',function(){
   updateTotal();
  })

});

app.controller('color', function($scope, CoatingService) {

  $scope.colors = CoatingService.colors;
  $scope.selected = CoatingService.selected;

  $scope.updateColor=function(color){
    $scope.selected.color=color;
    $scope.$emit('doPriceUpdate')
  }  

});
/* similar pattern for coating controller*/
```

You could do this all within one controller though quite easily with less code but still keep the service to store data

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Aot3EhfhjiuTDxluTca6?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: It works! Thank you! Now I will have to understand it and implement in my application. However, you and @Neikos have touched the subject of using multiple lists and values in one controller. That would be the best solution for me, but I had to reject it several days ago, because I could not create several separate ng-repeat'ed lists. See http://plnkr.co/edit/3kGyGhKk9wdwqesMyY5q?p=preview on the top, I have two lists, but when I choose one value, the other cancels. Do you know how to solve this? In that case it would be much easier for my app. Thank you again.

Comment: Here's that same demo you just sent, turned into one controller including price calc. Very little modification required. Also standardized `name` and `price` in data  http://plnkr.co/edit/XvJEZLsZHdGGFnsdmXFe?p=preview

Comment: Wow, that is much better alternative to Services, in my case. I will implement this, and parallel to that, I will also try to understand the services you have kindly described to me before.

Comment: the main concept you need to understand from the services demo is that objects are shared by reference. `var a={}, b=a`. Anything you do to property in `b` or `a` will do same in other...they are references to the exact same object. Must understand this concept working with angular, it is built on leveraging that inheritance

Comment: conversely..need to understand ramifications of nesting scopes also. Best to use new controllers for non related functionality, in this case all 3 are closely related